# How to determine general form of line equation in 3D from 2 points without using vectors, matrices, etc

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, analytic-geometry, numerical-linear-algebra, 3d

For a 2D line equation in General Form ($ax + by + c = 0$) it is possible to calculate all coefficients from two given points as follows:

$a = y_1-y_2$

$b = x_2-x_1$

$c = (x_1-x_2) y_1 + (y_2-y_1) x_1$

For a 3D line equation in General Form ($ax + by + cz + d = 0$) is there an equivalent method of calculating the coefficients?

P.S. I took the equations above from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13242738/how-can-i-find-the-general-form-equation-of-a-line-from-two-points).

Comment: The "general form" $ax+by+cz+d=0$ is the equation of a plane in 3D, not a line.

Comment: $ax+by+cz+d=0$ is a plane, not a line.  The scalar form of a line in $3$D is $$\frac{x-x_0}{a} = \frac{y-y_0}{b} = \frac{z-z_0}{c}$$  Notice that one scalar equation just won't do.  Also notice that this won't work if any of $a$, $b$, or $c$ is $0$.  The vector equation doesn't have these deficiencies.

Comment: three points determine a plane. two points determine a line

Comment: So are there no simple equations to calculate a, b, and c as there are for the 2D line?

Comment: I am afraid you need at least 2 polynomial equations to define a line in $\mathbb{R}^3$. In effect, each equation will reduce the number of dimensions of the solution set by at most 1.

Answer (score 1):

As comments already told you, $ax+by+cz+d=0$ is a plane. There are various ways to describe lines in 3d. The one which might be closest to what you do is using [Plücker coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pl%C3%BCcker_coordinates).

Let's look at the planar case for comparison. Start by appending a 1 (homogenization constant) to both coordinate vectors. Then compute all $2\times2$ determinants of that.

$$
\begin{pmatrix}x_1&x_2\\y_1&y_2\\1&1\end{pmatrix}
\\
\begin{vmatrix}y_1&y_2\\1&1\end{vmatrix} = y_1-y_2 = a \quad
\begin{vmatrix}x_1&x_2\\1&1\end{vmatrix} = x_1-x_2 = -b \quad
\begin{vmatrix}x_1&x_2\\y_1&y_2\end{vmatrix} = x_1y_2-x_2y_1 = c
$$

My $c$ looks different from yours because you can cancel one $x_1y_1$ after expanding things, so there is no real difference. The key messages here are

1. The $2\times2$ determinants contain all the information you need to describe the line.
2. Scaling all three numbers together by any non-zero number still represents the same line (homogeneous).

Now do the same for 3d. Start with

\begin{pmatrix}x_1&x_2\\y_1&y_2\\z_1&z_2\\1&1\end{pmatrix}

and compute all $2\times2$ determinants of that. There are 6 of these, and the convention I'm used to is using two indices for them, like $a_{12},a_{13},a_{14},a_{23},a_{24},a_{34}$. Or $a_{xy},a_{xz},a_{xw},a_{yz},a_{yw},a_{zw}$ if you prefer. Doesn't really matter. There also exist various conventions on how to assign signs to these. I know a formalism which would leave all six signs just as they come out of the determinant (and therefore would lead to an opposite sign in the $b$ of the planar case), putting the signs into the operations instead.

The above six numbers are not independent. They will always satisfy the equation $a_{12}a_{34}-a_{13}a_{24}+a_{14}a_{23}=0$. So if you know 5 of the numbers, you can derive the sixth unless its partner in this equation happens to be zero. And the coordinates are again homogeneous: scaling all numbers by the same factor (e.g. by $-1$ when swapping all signs) still represents the same line.

There are things you can compute using the Plücker coordinates of a line: compute the plane spanned by that and a third point, or intersect it with a plane to get a point, or check whether two lines in space intersect. But providing all the details here is too much for a single answer. Unfortunately the book describing this the way I learned it is in German.