# What is the geometric interpretation of the following relation for minor matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> **Definition:** For a $2 \times 4$ matrix $A$ let $A_{ij}$ be the associated $[ij]$-minor, i.e. the determinant of the $2 \times 2$ matrix whose columns are $i$-th and $j$-th column of the matrix $A$.

By this notation I can prove the following for $B\in M(\Bbb R, 2\times 4)$ by doing some algebraic calculations:

$$B_{12} · B_{34} − B_{13} · B_{24} + B_{14} · B_{23} = 0$$

> **Question:** what is its geometric interpretation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a particular case of Grassman-Plücker relationships [see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3493608) which can be qualified as "geometric" as dealing with a representation of lines in 3D ; see for that(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pl%C3%BCcker_embedding) (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klein_quadric) as being linked to the differential geometry of Grassmannian manifold $G(2,4)$ (see for example [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/230710/88984)).

**Edit :** See Plücker coordinates article (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pl%C3%BCcker_coordinates). See also this clear answer (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1612754).

Comment: It is also linked to [Cauchy-Binet formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Binet_formula)

Comment: See page 6 of this document which necessitates to understand the so-called "geometric algebra" : (https://www.garretstar.com/sob16-0102019.pdf).